# How to push Flutter project to Github and have other members download the same project?

Tags: github, flutter

I am making a Flutter application in Android Studio and i would like to throw it on a blank repo I have in my Github account. Is there a proper way to push the Flutter app that will allow my group members to be able to download the same project and work on it?

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the purposes of a repository. Being able to work together with people on a project. You should setup your repository and have your files uploaded to that repository. Once you have done that, go to settings of that specific repository, click collaborators (somewhere on the left side), and there should be a field which allows you to add other people to that repository via invite, so that they can work on it.

Comment: I trying to figure out what specific files to push on my repo that will allow my team members to work on the same project with me. Should i just upload the files we work on and tell me to create new projects or is there a way to upload my entire project on github?